# java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService: is it possible to wait for a service to finish before starting another one?

Tags: java, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I set 2 services in my web.xml and I create for each a shedule service as this:

```
public class MyScheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = null;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        if ((scheduledExecutorService == null) || (!scheduledExecutorService.isTerminated())) {
            scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyScheduledTimer(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

class MyScheduledTimer extends TimerTask {

    {
        try {
            MyEjb ejbObject = (InterfaceEjb) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/project/MyEjb");

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyScheduler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //my code to run with ejbObject...
    }
}
```

I would like to run first service to startup my application, waiting that this service is completed and after run the second service. Is it possibile?

Comment: yes, you can do it. keep a boolean flag and return true if your first service is done. then check for that flag before you call your second service inside the run method.

Comment: Ok, I had thought about this solution but I believe that ScheduledExecutorService class had some feature to allow this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something more specific - you can use CountDownLatch for example. Create

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CoundownLatch(1);
```

First service will call `countDown()`, when finishes his work.

```
//service1
public void run(){
    doSmthng();
    latch.countDown();
}
```

And second service will wait until latch counter not equals 0.

```
//service2
public void run(){
    latch.await();
    doSmthngElse();
}
```